# What does the phrase "Varies most rapidly" in a list of dimension mean?

Tags: c, verilog, system-verilog

For example:

```
bit [1:10] v1 [1:5];     //1 to 10 varies most rapidly; compatible with memory arrays
bit v2 [1:5][1:10];      //1 to 10 varies most rapidly, compatible with C;
```

Comment: Consider the numbers from 0 to 49. If you enumerate them, the ones place "varies most rapidly" and the tens place varies slower. For you arrays that means that `v2[j][i]` and `v2[j][i + 1]` are adjacent in memory, but `v2[j][i]` and `v2[j + 1][i]` are not. (Both `v1` and `v2` have the same memoty layout, only the way you define them is different.)

Comment: Those lines of code are from the IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 7.4.5 *Multidimensional arrays*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you line up all the elements by their order in memory(or as a bit-stream), the dimension whose index whose index that would change between each element is the one that *varies most rapidly*. The memory layout does not matter so much since SystemVerilog has no pointers. But is does matter when you try to select parts of an array, the index selecting goes from least to most varying.

`v1[2][3]` is 2 of 5 followed by 3 of 10.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @dave_59 said, it matters if you use `foreach`, eg:

```
module M;
  bit [1:10] v1 [1:5];
  initial
    foreach(v1[i,j])
      $display("v1[%0d][%0d]= %b", i, j, v1[i][j]);      
endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5b9m

displays

```
# KERNEL: v1[1][1]= 0
# KERNEL: v1[1][2]= 0
# KERNEL: v1[1][3]= 0
# KERNEL: v1[1][4]= 0
# KERNEL: v1[1][5]= 0
# KERNEL: v1[1][6]= 0
# KERNEL: v1[1][7]= 0
# KERNEL: v1[1][8]= 0
# KERNEL: v1[1][9]= 0
# KERNEL: v1[1][10]= 0
# KERNEL: v1[2][1]= 0
# KERNEL: v1[2][2]= 0
...
# KERNEL: v1[5][7]= 0
# KERNEL: v1[5][8]= 0
# KERNEL: v1[5][9]= 0
# KERNEL: v1[5][10]= 0
```

You can see that the `j` dimension, the size-10 dimension, the *packed* dimension "varies most rapidly".